# How to always display the prefix namespace in Simple framework?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-namespaces, simple-framework

### Issue with `XML` prefixes

I would like to have the prefix always displayed on every child of my `XML`.
For that, I annotated each of the classes with corresponding `@Namespace(reference = "uri", prefix = "pre")`, and annotated the attributes with `@Namespace(reference = "uri")`.

So for some of my annotated classes, I get the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pre:myClass1 xmlns:pre="uri" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
  <pre:attr1>value1</pre:attr1>
  <pre:attr2>value2</pre:attr2>
<pre:myClass1>
```

But some others, I get this (unprefixed result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass2 xmlns="uri" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
  <attr1>value1</attr1>
  <attr2>value2</attr2>
<myClass2>
```

As you can see, it gives the prefix `xmime` to the second namespace, and just puts the namespace `uri` to the current node, without putting the prefix everywhere. I know it is not supposed to change the *meaning* of the `XML` file, but the **norm** I have to follow specifies that the prefix should appear everywhere.

---

### Annotated `Java` classes

My classes look like this:

```java
@NamespaceList(value = {
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime", prefix = "xmime"),
        @Namespace(reference = "uri", prefix = "pre") })
public abstract class Ancestor {
  ...
}
```

And both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` extend `Ancestor` in the same way.

```java
@Namespace(reference = "uri", prefix = "pre")
public class MyClass1 extends Ancestor { // Or MyClass2
    @Element(required = false)
    @Namespace(reference = "uri")
    protected String attr1;
    @Element(required = false)
    @Namespace(reference = "uri")
    protected String attr2;
}
```

---

### Why and how?

Why is there such a difference in the XML output, and how to obtain the prefixed version?

*Could it even be a bug or so?*